# What's the point of instantiating an object and not assigning it to a variable in Java?

Tags: java

What is the use of the `new` keyword when you don't assign the resulting object to a reference?

here is sample.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {ample.
    Display display = new Display();

    new SWTApp(display);

    display.dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the use of the new keyword when you don't assign the resulting object to a reference

When you want to call some method of a class *only once* and *don't* want to store the object's reference for future use in. In the example below I am only interested to call the method `showMessage()` of the `Display` class.

```
public class XYTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Display().showMessage();
    }
}

class Display {

    public void showMessage() {
        System.out.println("Hey! I am here.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

In your case, most probably, the constructor has a side-effect (launching the application in a thread?) and you are exclusively interested in that side-effect.

Look at it like an ugly way of invoking a method.

Comment: I don't think it'll be in a different thread - otherwise we'd end up disposing of the display before it's finished. Or else it could start a new thread but then block the current thread...

Comment: given the uglyness of the code above, I wouldn't be too surprised if `dispose()` actually awaits the thread launched and registered by `SWTApp` but yes, a blocking constructor looks like the saner approach here.

Comment: This is the offending code: http://zetcode.com/gui/javaswt/introduction/
the constructor is a blocking one, you are right.

Answer (score 4):

Presumably in this case the constructor for `SWTApp` actually runs the application until it's closed. That doesn't sound like a great design to me, but there's nothing in the language to actually prevent it.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to create a new object but don't need to set anything for that object then you don't need to assign it to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, new keyword is used to create an object. Now what happens when an object is created, JVM allocates memory for all the member variables and methods, AND constructor is invoked. In normal cases you would like to store the variable reference to some object, but if you know that whatever you wanted from the new object is already being done by constructor, you can go for the initialization you mentioned (though a very bad practice)

For example

```
public class PrintFile{
public PrintFile(String fileName)
{
//code to print the file on printer or file system
}
}
```

Now we can simply say

```
new PrintFile(filetoprint);
```

No need to save the object reference as the work is done in the constructor itself.

Answer (score 0):

The Standard Widget Toolkit (SWT) is a graphical widget toolkit for the Java programming language.

Graphical applications regardless of platform have discrete entry points which create viewable resources and queueing mechanisms to fire events between those resources and to call controller objects in your application as a result. (eg button action events, window open events)

The fact that you dont need to save a reference to one of these objects is not that relevant as constructors like these are generally representations of application entry points that you do not need to deal with directly.

The constructor is not manipulating the object you pass it, it is accepting it as a starting point for executing an application in a context, possibly using the initial state you pass in as the initial window or initial configuration.

Here is the code of the constructor you are curious about:

```
public SWTApp(Display display) {

    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setText("Center");
    shell.setSize(250, 200);

    center(shell);

    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
      if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
        display.sleep();
      }
    }
}
```

Build your app and dont worry about this, its not a user relevant instance, its an application entry point. Incidentally this initial construction for a graphical application looks like just about every other entry point for a graphical application in almost any language.

Cheers!