# If a constructor is called with new keyword, does it create an object?

Tags: java, object, constructor, new-operator

I read somewhere that a *constructor* can't  be called without creating an object in Java. However, in the following piece of code, they use the *new* keyword to call the *constructor* of the class. My question is, is it creating any object here? If so, how can I access a nameless object?

```
class Bike10{

final int speedlimit;//blank final variable  

Bike10(){  
speedlimit=70;  
System.out.println(speedlimit);  
}  

public static void main(String args[]){  
  new Bike10();  
  }  
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "a nameless object"?

Comment: Yes, it is created. You should see that from the `println()` running. And no, you can not access it without storing somewhere.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the point of instantiating an object and not assigning it to a variable in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11721199/whats-the-point-of-instantiating-an-object-and-not-assigning-it-to-a-variable-i)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it creates a new object. However there is no reference retained to that object, so after it's done doing it's thing, it will be eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: *"it will be "eligible for" garbage collected"*, schematics ;) (I should point out that you answer is correct with and without it :D)

Comment: @MadProgrammer blue prints even

Comment: @MadProgrammer Not just semantics - knowing when and how something will be cleaned up can actually be quite important from a performance and memory management perspective.